# Get Path cordinates into my JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html, xml, snap.svg, inkscape

I created a Path with Inkscape, can i somehow get the coordinates (path) out of the SVG file into my JavaScript file with something like getElementByID? Posted the code of the Path down below. I am also using SNAP.svg if it is possible to do it with that just leave your answer thanks! I want to get the d="m 110.36905......." out of the svg file into my javascript file

```
<path
         inkscape:original-d="m 110.36905,95.916669 v 52.160711 h 92.98214 v 40.06548"
         inkscape:path-effect="#path-effect821"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
         id="L_PUF_AKL"
         d="m 110.36905,95.916669 c 0,11.243311 -0.0171,30.565001 -0.0389,52.160711 0,-3.5e-4 -4e-5,0.0393 -4e-5,0.0389 -0.006,0 0.0452,3e-5 0.039,2e-5 30.13329,0.0171 62.75026,0.0372 92.88868,0.0543 -0.0218,16.55036 -0.0388,31.35222 -0.0388,39.9722 0,0 0.13229,0 0.13229,0 0,0 0.13229,0 0.13229,0 0,-8.63617 -0.0171,-23.47747 -0.0389,-40.06548 0,5e-5 -1.3e-4,-0.0934 -1.3e-4,-0.0934 -0.001,0 -0.0917,5e-5 -0.0932,5e-5 -30.15147,0.0171 -62.78962,0.0372 -92.94323,0.0544 -0.0219,-21.57998 -0.0389,-40.88518 -0.0389,-52.121731 z"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1;fill-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none" />
```

Comment: You question isn't very clear. Are you loading in the inkscape file ? If so, you can do console.log( Snap("#L_PUF_AKL").attr('d') ), after it has loaded in.

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a `svg`-element, insert the path as `innerHTML` into it and retrieve its `d`-attribute.

```js
const svg = document.createElement("svg");
svg.innerHTML = `<path
   inkscape:original-d="m 110.36905,95.916669 v 52.160711 h 92.98214 v 40.06548"
   inkscape:path-effect="#path-effect821"
   inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
   id="L_PUF_AKL"
   d="m 110.36905,95.916669 c 0,11.243311 -0.0171,30.565001 -0.0389,52.160711 0,-3.5e-4 -4e-5,0.0393 -4e-5,0.0389 -0.006,0 0.0452,3e-5 0.039,2e-5 30.13329,0.0171 62.75026,0.0372 92.88868,0.0543 -0.0218,16.55036 -0.0388,31.35222 -0.0388,39.9722 0,0 0.13229,0 0.13229,0 0,0 0.13229,0 0.13229,0 0,-8.63617 -0.0171,-23.47747 -0.0389,-40.06548 0,5e-5 -1.3e-4,-0.0934 -1.3e-4,-0.0934 -0.001,0 -0.0917,5e-5 -0.0932,5e-5 -30.15147,0.0171 -62.78962,0.0372 -92.94323,0.0544 -0.0219,-21.57998 -0.0389,-40.88518 -0.0389,-52.121731 z"
   style="fill:#000000;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1;fill-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none" 
/>`;
console.log(svg.querySelector("path").getAttribute("d"));
```

Comment: do i add this in my svg file or in my javascript file? cause i want the path directly from the svg file

Comment: This is javascript. You'll have to read the contents of the svg-file somehow and create the element. If it's server side, you'll need some library to be able to create a DOM-tree. If that's not an option you have to fiddle with regular expression, or string manipulation.

Comment: yeah i am working with snap.svg where i run the script on my xampp server. But is it possible to get the d straight out of the svg file ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not well versed in xampp or snap.svg. The ideas are in the answer and comment, you must figure out the way to execute them within your framework yourself.